# How to identify the feature that make the model misclassifed in text classification

Tags: nlp, text-mining, accuracy, text-classification, text

Hi I am working on social media financial **THAI** text classification, the problem with this one is the confused classes, the misclassified prediction has a pattern that consistent as a pair.

and I want to know how can I identify the word/feature that responsible for the misclassified and lead the model to confuse with the prediction?

Answer (score 0):

I think we would need more information about the model architecture you are using and the features you engineered for training.

Something I like to do when starting to work on text classification problems is to gradually increase the complexity of the architecture and start from simple approaches.

So if you are using `tf-idf` features and some sort of probabilistic model, such as `logistic regression` you may have a look at libraries such as [Lime](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime) or [eli5](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5) that can help you make sense and explain the prediction of your classification model.
In your case you may then look at the top-features of the misclassified text and increase your understanding of why the model derived at its decision.